# How to remove a table row that contains the cell with some data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
<tr><th>Content</th><th>Show in table</th></tr>
<tr><td>ABC</td><td>True</td></tr>
<tr><td>ABC</td><td>False</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to show only this rows, which have

```
<td>True</td>
```

and additionally I want to remove "Show in table" column from finally html file. How can I do it in jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You can use contains selector:

```
$('tr:contains("Show in table")').remove();
```

and

```
$('tr:contains("True")').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// First removes the rows which have false in second column
$("tr").has("td:contains(False)").remove();

// Then remove the second column from the table.
$("table tr td:eq(1), table tr th:eq(1)").remove();
```